# Ajax Array to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have dynamic Html Form Elements.

```
 <input type="text" name='myInputs[]'>
```

And my Ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"./ajax/xxxxx.php",
            data:{ 'something': 'something'},
            success: function(data){

            }
        });
```

My Question is how can i get the inputs from all my from elements 
over Ajax to my PHP File ?

Thanks

Comment: See jQuery's [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
data = $('#Form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request the value of an input field via jquery by using `$(name='nameOfFields').val();`

If there are multiple fields with the same name this should return an array which you can use. Otherwise you can work with id's and make an array yourself.

Answer (score 0):

in xxxx.php you just have $variable_name = $_POST['something'];

```
  <input type="text" class="myInputs" name="myInputs[]">

  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"./ajax/myFile.php",
        data:{ 'something': $('.myInputs').val()},
        success: function(data){

        }
  });
```

here is myFile.php:

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST['something'];
```